# which visual studio version should i use for asp.net framework 1.1 live maintenance

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, frameworks

We have asp.net 1.1 framework application is in live environment with appx 200 users.

Which visual studio version is safe to use for maintenance?

We are not planning to migrate yet. I am using vs 2008 for developing a 3.5 application right now so not want to take the risk of visual studio conversion.

Answer (score 0):

You can check with visual studio2005 version

Comment: Are you sure that VS2005 supports targeting .NET 1.x?

Answer (score 0):

Use Visual Studio .NET 2003 and MSDN Library of Jan 2006.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use any Visual studio once your project is targeting the correct framework. [This Post](https://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2008/06/02/installing-asp-net-1-1-with-iis7-on-vista-and-windows-2008.aspx) talks you through installing aspt 1.1 on a windows 8 machine.